# not able to get inputstream in server socket file transfer

Tags: java, swing, serversocket

I have developed a screen in swings to download a file from the server. The whole concept works fine when i click the download button once. But when i click the download button second time, i find that the code pauses in getting the *inputstream*.(this i have followed it using the sysouts shown.)

Below shown are the two separate code snippets in two different files. TCPClient has the serversocket codings whereas the clientUI has the ui components which calls the TCPSever method to accept a socket and for requesting purpose.

In the tcp client side:

```
  public TCPClient() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Inside TCPClient constructor---");
    clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3500);
    System.out.println("After creating socket instance---");
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("after getting the ouput stream---");
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("after getting the input stream.");
    }
```

In the Client UI:

```
private void downloadButton_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws Exception 
{ 
    Object selectedItem = contentsList.getSelectedValue();
        System.out.println("selectedItem---"+selectedItem);
        new TCPClient().downloadContents(nodeName,selectedItem.toString());
    }
}
```

Kindly provide me a solution for this...

```
Below is the server code:

    public void listening() throws Exception{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3500);
            System.out.println( "DataServer Is Listening..." );

            while( true )
            {
                Socket soc = ss.accept();

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());                                                            
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( soc.getOutputStream() );
String input = ( String ) ois.readObject( );

if(input.startsWith("downloadContents")){
            String nodeName = ois.readObject().toString();
            String contentName = ois.readObject().toString();
            List contentsForNode = DBServer.getContentsForNode(nodeName);
            for(Object obj : contentsForNode){
                if(obj.toString().contains(contentName)){
                    new FileServer().send(obj.toString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) 
        {
            TCPServer obDataServer  = new TCPServer();

            try
            {
                obDataServer.listening();
            }
            catch ( Exception ioe )
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: how can you found that Stream(s) paused, what happens with file(s),

Comment: @mkorbel I find all the sysouts except after the inputstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, your server is single-threaded and is still reading its input stream, because you haven't closed the client socket. But it's anybody's guess until you post the relevant server code.

Comment: @mKorbel your question is irrelevant both to my answer and to his current problem. If you have an answer of your own let's have it.

Comment: @Arun so, as I guessed, your server is indeed single threaded and your client doesn't close the connection. So fix one of those, preferably both.

Comment: @EJP there are three possibles areas, 1) Concurency on some of Enviroments, 2) File's Concurency, 3) Concurency in Swing,  3a) this code is pretty out of EDT, 3b) running long and hard code started from EDT, then my question to your person, becasue OTN :-) and your endless skills about Networks

Comment: @mKorbel That makes 5, not 3. His client is never getting out of new ObjectInputStream() the 2nd time. That has nothing to do with Swing, or concurrency on files, or anything except the structure of his client and server.

Comment: @Arun Your client never closes the connection, so your server can never get out of that read loop to process the next connection.

Comment: @EJP  ... :-) then there I see only 4 described, what is last :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you take care of closing the socket after the file is downloaded (successfully/unsuccessfully)? It doesn't looks like it from the code snippet.

I'm not sure, but this might be the problem

Comment: I ve not closed the socket but it works for the other process. Like, first im looking for the list of files for download using new TCPClient().getContentsForNode(nodeName) . I m not facing any problem during this. but when i click the same download button twice, im not able to get inputstream. If socket closing is the problem, then i should ve had a problem during the getOutputstream() method. Please tell me is there any possible solution for this.

Comment: Can you provide more code (as suggested by [EJP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp))

Comment: I have added the server code as well. Here i use a separate server socket connection for the file transfer. So, the FileServer and FileClient are separate files which are basically made for file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

This Is Server Class:

```
package client_to_server;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;`
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(2222);
        System.out.println("New Server is Waiting");
        Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("My Connection Established");
        DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        String starttime=df.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println("Start time is : "+starttime);
        InputStream inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] readbyte=new byte[(1024*20)*1024];       
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream("/home/Manoj/copybulkfile5.zip");
        int writebyte;
        int count=0;
        while((writebyte=inputStream.read(readbyte))!=-1)
        {
            if(writebyte>0)
                count+=writebyte;
            fileOutputStream.write(readbyte, 0, writebyte);
        }
        DateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
        String endtime=df1.format(c1.getTime());
        System.out.println("END TIME is "+endtime);
        System.out.println("THE WRITEBYTE VALUE IS "+writebyte+"THE READ BYTE VALUE IS"+count);
        inputStream.close();


    }

}
```

This Is Client Cass:

```
package client_to_server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        //Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",2222);
        Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",2222);
        File file=new File("/home/Checking/Myfile.zip");
        byte[] mybyte=new byte[(1024*20)*1024];
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(file);
        int count;
        OutputStream outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
        while((count=fileInputStream.read(mybyte))!=-1)
        {
            outputStream.write(mybyte);
        }
        System.out.println("THIS FILE HAS BEEN SENT SUCCESSFULLY!!!");

        //System.out.println("END TIME "+hr+"Hours"+min+"Minutes "+sec+"Seconds");
        socket.close();
    }
}
```